# Where can I find a tool or server to generate tiles nodes cordinates?

Tags: software, tiles

Does anyone know a tool or a server that can generate the node coordinates for different tiles?

I would like to create 2D materials based in some periodic tiles like the ones in the image below:

[image: The 14 Different Types of Convex Pentagons that Tile the Plane]

More info about tiles: [1](https://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/), [2](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/tilepent.html) and [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the [Reticular Chemistry Structure Resource](http://rcsr.anu.edu.au/about). The website has 3D, 2D, 1D, and 0D nets / tilings.

At the moment, there are [200 2D layers](http://rcsr.anu.edu.au/layers). You can filter by numbers of vertices, coordination numbers, etc.

There are some resources associated with the [Gavrog / Systre](http://gavrog.org) project for analyzing tilings as well.

These tilings are focused generally on "things that exist", while some of your tilings seem a bit abstract. For those, I'd suggest using image analysis software or something like [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org) in Python to find the intersections and derive the coordinates yourself (e.g., using a [Hough transform](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html) or contour-finding).